# 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.dll, CategoryName is missing

Tags: c#, .net

I'm currently doing a basic coding course in C#, and right now I'm working on Windows Forms in Visual Studio.

When I go to launch my program (a very basic calculator), I get this error:

[image]

All this stuff seems to have been added automatically by Visual Studio, so I'm not sure why it's crashing.

If I remove the line highlighted the program will run normally and work fine, I'm just confused why it's even there, and why something added automatically would cause an exception like this.

For more information about the program, here is the full code for the form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinForm_Activity_27
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int num1, num2 = 0;
            string calcType = "";
            if (!((Int32.TryParse(textNum1.Text, out num1)) && (Int32.TryParse(textNum2.Text, out num2))))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Thats not right.");
                return;
            }

            foreach (RadioButton rdo in grpMathOptions.Controls)
            {
                if (rdo.Checked == true)
                {
                    calcType = rdo.Text;
                }                    
            }

            switch(calcType)
            {
                case "Addition": textResult.Text = (num1 + num2).ToString();
                    break;
                case "Subtraction": textResult.Text = (num1 - num2).ToString();
                    break;
                case "Multiplication": textResult.Text = (num1 * num2).ToString();
                    break;
                case "Division": textResult.Text = ((Double)num1 / (Double)num2).ToString();
                    break;
            }
        }//end of btnCalculate_Click
    }
}
```

Any idea of why this error is happening and how I can stop it from happening again in future projects would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: In which line do u get this exception ?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you inadvertently dropped a performance counter on your form.
delete 
private System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter performanceCounter1 and follow the squiggly lines.

Comment: Same problem, same solution. Thumbs up, upvodted. Hell it would take me a week to figure this out without forums...